# all subset of a se in julia

Tags: julia, julia-jump

would you please help me? 
How can I do a code which can find all subset of a set

for example

I want to code this constraint in Julia. It is a subtour constraint. But I don't know how I can find all subsets of S set.

[image]

```
@constraint(ILRP,
            c7[k in totalK, t in totalH],
            sum(x[i,j,k,t] for i=1:totalS, j=1:totalS)<=size(S)-1);
```

Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know whether this is what you seek:

> using Combinatorics
>
> ```
>    function subsets(A::AbstractArray,r::Union{AbstractArray,Integer})
>   o= Array{Array{eltype(A),1},1}(undef,0)         
>   if typeof(r)<:Integer
>       r>length(A) && (r=[length(A)])
>       r=[r...]
>   elseif typeof(r)<:UnitRange
>       r[end]>length(A) && (r=1:r[length(A)])
>   else
>       !issubset(r,1:length(A)) && (r=intersect(r,1:length(A)))
>   end
>   for n = r
>       a=combinations(A,n)
>       for i in a     
>           push!(o,i)
>       end
>   end
>   return o
> end
>
> subsets(A::AbstractArray) = subsets(A,1:length(A))
> ```

It can List all Subsets or Subsets up to a certain limit (length): eg:

> ```
>  julia> subsets(1:3)
>  7-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
>   [1]
>   [2]
>   [3]
>   [1, 2]
>   [1, 3]
>   [2, 3]
>   [1, 2, 3]
>   julia> subsets(1:3,2)
>   3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
>   [1, 2]
>   [1, 3]
>   [2, 3]
> ```

Answer (score 8):

You can get it using `powerset` function from the Combinatorics.jl package, e.g.:

```
julia> using Combinatorics

julia> x = [1:5;]
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5

julia> powerset(x)
Base.Iterators.Flatten{Array{Combinatorics.Combinations{Array{Int64,1}},1}}(Combinatorics.Combinations{Array{Int64,1}}[Combinations{Array{Int64,1}}([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0), Combinations{Array{Int64,1}}([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 1), Combinations{Array{Int64,1}}([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2), Combinations{Array{Int64,1}}([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3), Combinations{Array{Int64,1}}([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4), Combinations{Array{Int64,1}}([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 5)])

julia> collect(powerset(x))
32-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 []
 [1]
 [2]
 [3]
 [4]
 [5]
 [1, 2]
 [1, 3]
 [1, 4]
 [1, 5]
 [2, 3]
 [2, 4]
 [2, 5]
 [3, 4]
 [3, 5]
 [4, 5]
 [1, 2, 3]
 [1, 2, 4]
 [1, 2, 5]
 [1, 3, 4]
 [1, 3, 5]
 [1, 4, 5]
 [2, 3, 4]
 [2, 3, 5]
 [2, 4, 5]
 [3, 4, 5]
 [1, 2, 3, 4]
 [1, 2, 3, 5]
 [1, 2, 4, 5]
 [1, 3, 4, 5]
 [2, 3, 4, 5]
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Note that by default `powerset` returns an iterator to avoid allocating all subsets.
Also you can pass a second and third positional argument to `powerset` to limit minimum and maximum size of the returned subset, e.g.:

```
julia> collect(powerset(x, 2, 3))
20-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2]
 [1, 3]
 [1, 4]
 [1, 5]
 [2, 3]
 [2, 4]
 [2, 5]
 [3, 4]
 [3, 5]
 [4, 5]
 [1, 2, 3]
 [1, 2, 4]
 [1, 2, 5]
 [1, 3, 4]
 [1, 3, 5]
 [1, 4, 5]
 [2, 3, 4]
 [2, 3, 5]
 [2, 4, 5]
 [3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I used your valuable helps. but when I use in constraints it gets me error.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I used your valuable helps. but when I use in constraints it gets me error.


"totalI=3;

s=[1:totalI;]

S=collect(powerset(s))


for i=2:size(S,1)
    @constraint(ILRP,c7[ k in totalK,t in totalH, s in size(S[i],1)],sum(x[i,j,k,t] for        i=1:size(S[i],1), j=1:size(S[i],1))<=size(S[i],1)-1)
end"



this error 

ERROR: UndefVarError: i not defined

if you don't mind, please help me gain why the code don't identify i

Comment: You are reusing `i` variable twice. Once in the outer loop and once inside the constraint. You should use unique variable names, e.g. change `for i=2:size(S,1)` to `for outer_i=2:size(S,1)` and correct the code inside to use `outer_i` appropriately.

Comment: if you don't mind, please help me again.

can I use powerset(x, 2:5)?

that it gives me only subsets with 2,3,4 and 5 elements.

Comment: `powerset(x, 2, 5)`

Comment: yes it is very useful. thanks veryyyyyyyyyyyyyy muchhhhhhhhhh. :)

Im sorry for asking again what you said before.